# ASP.Net Identity login from existing Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Here is my scenario.

I developing MVC 5 application with Identity 2 in place and it running standalone fine.
Older application already have it own custom user table with username and password encrypted.
I would like to have a link from old application and open this new MVC 5 application in new window and authenticated automatically.

I have looking into OWIN but fail. I am totally new in Identity and OWIN.

Appreciate if the any samples link and step.